# Wicket: Relative to absolute URL or get base URL

Tags: java, url, wicket

If I have a relative path to a static asset (flash/blah.swf), what is the best way to programmatically convert this to an absolute URL (http://localhost/app/flash/blah.swf)? Or what is the best way to get the base URL of the Wicket application? I've tried using RequestUtils.toAbsolutePath but it doesn't seem to work reliably and is frequently throwing exceptions. This needs to work on all servers the app is deployed to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
RequestUtils.toAbsolutePath(RequestCycle.get().getRequest().
  getRelativePathPrefixToWicketHandler());
```

worked for me.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work in Wicket 1.5, which has no single arg `toAbsolutePath`

Answer (score 13):

For Wicket 6 it is

```
String absoluteUrl = RequestCycle.get().getUrlRenderer().renderFullUrl(Url.parse("my-relative-url.html"));
```

Comment: And base URL is `String baseUrl = RequestCycle.get().getUrlRenderer().getBaseUrl().toString()`

Answer (score 1):

For Wicket 1.5 there is information [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Getting+a+url+for+display)

Answer (score 0):

`org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.servlet.ServletWebRequest` has a method `getRelativePathPrefixToContextRoot()` (actually defined as abstract in a superclass).

A standard idiom for using it is

```
RequestCycle.get().getRequest().getRelativePathPrefixToContextRoot() + location;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using something like this after adding a `base_url` property to my `MyApplication` class that extends the wicket application.

```
MyApplication app = (MyApplication)getApplication();
String appBaseUrl = app.getBaseUrl(); 
if (StringUtils.isEmpty(appBaseUrl)) { 
    appBaseUrl = RequestUtils.toAbsolutePath(urlFor(app.getHomePage(), new PageParameters()).toString());
    app.setBaseUrl(appBaseUrl); 
} 

// Add base URL to <script wicket:id="base_url"></script> to use with Flash
add(new Label("base_url", "base_url = \"" + appBaseUrl + "\";").setEscapeModelStrings(false));
```